# AWS S3 media transfer slow & pause when application send to background in IOS

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, upload, file-transfer, awss3transfermanager

I am developing an chat app where I transfer media like videos / audio/ images.

When the transfer is done with below code snippet, the transfer is smooth on Wifi but is very very slow when moved to 3G network.

Also another issue is when I go in background the AWS SDK pause the transfer and resumes when I come in foreground.

1) How can I make the transfer fast as I have tried changing the AWS region still no success.
2) Also use the S3Background transfer example compared to AWS S3 transfer manager used but the download paused when I press home button.

Below is my code snipped.

//Upload function

AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

```
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName;

User *userMO = .....my user details 

NSString *fileName = [[filePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];

uploadRequest.key = [userMO.user_pool_id stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSURL *uploadFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

uploadRequest.body = uploadFileURL;

uploadRequest.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];


NSString *fileContentTypeStr = @"image/jpg";

if ([FileManager isVideoFile:fileName]) {
    //        fileContentTypeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video/%@",[[fileName pathExtension] lowercaseString]];
    fileContentTypeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video/quicktime"];
}
else if ([FileManager isImageFile:fileName]) {
    fileContentTypeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image/%@",[[fileName pathExtension] lowercaseString]];
}
else if ([FileManager isAudioFile:fileName]) {
    fileContentTypeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"audio/%@",[[fileName pathExtension] lowercaseString]];
}

uploadRequest.contentType = fileContentTypeStr;

[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

    if (task.error) {

        if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
            switch (task.error.code) {
                case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                {
                        //updating ui to notify cancel

                }
                    break;
                case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                {
                        //updating ui to notify paused
                }
                    break;

                default:
                {
                    NSLog(@"Upload task failed: %@",[task.error localizedDescription]);
                        //updating ui to notify failed
                }
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Upload task failed: %@",[task.error localizedDescription]);
                        //updating ui to notify failed

        }
    }

    if (task.result)
    {
                        //updating ui to notify finished
    }
 return nil;
 }];


if(uploadRequest.state == AWSS3TransferManagerRequestStateRunning)
{
                        //updating ui to notify progress
}

//Add the request to the current upload cache handler entry as handle
```

Any body have any suggestions and faced similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS background transfer not AWS transfer manager to use the background mode supported transfer.